# What is the maximum precision required for monetary values?

Tags: types, currency

Typically you use `double` or `decimal` for monetary values in .NET. What is the maximum precision required for monetary values in terms of decimal points, for database-side storage, not during computation.

- **INR :** Indian Rupees have paise -> 1.25 means 1 rupee and 25 paise. The max precision is 2 digits after the decimal. You simply cannot have 25.2 paise.
- **USD :** US Dollars have cents -> 1.25 means 1 dollar and 25 cents. Is the max precision 2 digits or is there ever a case where sub-cent values are taken into account?
- **Other :** I'm assuming other major currencies would be treated the same way as USD?

Comment: Depends on what your using them for. Shops obviously dont but trading/financial/currency markets do.

Comment: depends totally on the situation

Answer (score 1):

Yes I think 2 digits after decimal would be fare enough to handle **most** of the currency values. However there may be a situation where you may get a value like 125 paise in some calculation but then too  you can convert that into Rs 1 and 25 paise. However when it comes to database side then if you are using SQL Server then `DECIMAL(19, 4)` is a popular choice to use for money transactions.

Also as others have commented it really depends as to how and where you are using these values. As for the example which you have provided lets take Rupees. Then 1 Rs has 100 paise which is for sure. But how you are going to use this 100 paise in your transaction depnds. That is whether you are going to convert the money once it reaches the 100 value into Rs or will  you like to store the value in paise only. So in both these situation the precision may vary.

Comment: Why 4 decimal places?

Comment: @Geotarget:- As I said its a popular choice as most of the financial firm keep track upto that place.

Comment: @Geotarget:- And as others have commented if you can tell us where you are going to use then it would be easy to determine it with more *precision* ;)

Comment: @Robinicks its because that is the maximum minor unit for a given ISO4217 currency. The Uruguay Unidad Previsional (UYW) is an example of this.